# Rails best practice for href in an ajax link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When creating a link that will be implemented unobtrusively in JavaScript, what is the best practice for populating the href attribute?

```
<%= link_to('My Ajax Link', '#') %>
<%= link_to('My Ajax Link', nil) %>
<%= link_to('My Ajax Link', 'javascript:void(0)') %>
```

I've always wondered!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a slight variation on your last example:

```
<%= link_to('My Ajax Link', 'javascript:;') %>
```

The first two examples using `'#'` and `nil` will reposition the scrollbar at the top of the page, which is not ideal in most situations.

Using `javascript:;` works the same as `javascript:void(0)`, but is more succinct.